# Adding image texture to procedural texture without colour alteration

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have a node setup consisting of a procedural texture, and an image texture. Alone, both are fine when plugged into the `Base Colour` input of a `Principled BSDF`. However, I have not found a way to combine the two without one texture affecting the other.

The most promising setup I have is to add the two textures using `Vector Math`, then plug that node into the `Principled BSDF` node. However, this causes the colour in the image texture to change from orange to yellow. The only other colour data in the image is alpha transparency.

I suspect the transparency might be the cause of this issue. If this is true, how do I go about adding the image texture on top of the procedural one, without altering either texture's colours?

EDIT: Example setup:

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots so we can see what you mean to do? I usually use an rgb mix node to combine textures and choose the mix mode appropriate for the result I want.

Comment: Done. Also, MixRGB with Mix causes the procedural texture to darken, Add causes the image texture to lighten, and I think pretty much every other option causes some sort of unwanted alteration. I know there has to be a way to put the two together unaltered, but I don't remember how.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to use an image texture with an alpha channel and have the procedural texture appear in the alpha areas? Otherwise you can't really have two textures covering the same area without them changing each other in some way...

Comment: I want the procedural texture to appear all over the applied mesh. As for the image texture, I've UV unwrapped and positioned it where I want it to be, but I don't want the alpha in the imported image to affect anything else. Worst case scenario, I'll just edit the image in GIMP.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a VectorMath node there, rather than a color blending node.
As Craig D Jones said, MixRGB is correct for color blending (like 'photoshop-layer' blending rules).

It's unclear what your goal is, but you appear to mean you want to just 'alpha over' the two inputs, when you say 'without affecting each other'.

One way to achieve that would be to pass the color data to Diffuse BSDFs, then use a Mix Shader to combine these (with 0.5 giving the middle result of some from each), and then take that shader output into a 'Converter > Shader to RGB' Node.

The 'Shader to RGB' node is under 'Converter', 3 items from the bottom of the menu, assuming you are editing an Object's Material nodes. It is not available in World nodes.

[image: screenshot showing Diffuse BSDF Nodes and Mix Shader node]

Comment: Where do I find the shader to RGB node? Not coming up in the node search.

Comment: (Edited reply to be more specific about that Node. It can also be searched under Shader to RGB). I think it's also quite a new node, actually. I don't remember the old way of doing this.

Comment: Further clarification: I was testing this answer out on default startup of Blender 2.80 - hence I was using Eevee. If you're on Cycles, that node isn't there.

Comment: No worries. I ended up using a RGB Curves node attached between the image texture and MixRGB. Looks like it solved the issue without affecting the procedural texture. Thanks for your time anyway.